# Changes value use in all functions (NASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have problem with accumulator eax. In main function I don't get true value. In set, I put eax to 1. Always accumulator is 8. Set function change value only in set function. How can use changes in all functions?

```
function:
mov edx, [esp +4]
cmp edx, 3
je set
ret

set:
mov eax,1
ret

main:
pushad
mov eax,0
mov, ebx,2
loop:
add ebx,1
call function
push eax
push something ; this is string db...
call printf ; always print number 8
add esp,8
cmp ebx, 4
jne loop
popad
ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing any arguments to `function`, so presumably the comparison will always be false and `eax` remains unchanged. The first time around it should be zero, from then on it's the return value from `printf` which may very well be `8`. You probably want to pass `ebx` as argument to `function` and either preserve `eax` through `printf` or zero it explicitly in `function`. For example:

```
main:
pushad
mov eax,0
mov ebx,2
loop:
add ebx,1
push ebx ; pass as argument
call function
add esp, 4 ; free argument
push eax ; save eax
push eax
push something ; this is string db...
call printf ; always print number 8
add esp,8
pop eax ; restore eax
cmp ebx, 4
jne loop
popad
ret
```

PS: Learn to use a debugger to find your own mistakes.

Here is the other version where `function` returns `0` or `1`:

```
function:
mov edx, [esp +4]
cmp edx, 3
je set
mov eax, 0
ret

set:
mov eax,1
ret

main:
pushad
mov ebx,2
loop:
add ebx,1
push ebx ; pass as argument
call function
add esp, 4 ; free argument
push eax
push something ; this is string db...
call printf ; always print number 8
add esp,8
cmp ebx, 4
jne loop
popad
ret
```

Comment: I do like this, but it's same. Sorry I'm begginer and don't know much.

Comment: Works fine here. But note that you don't ever reset `eax`, so it will print `1` twice.